# Wrong Callback gets fired while verifying received OTP using Sinch SMS Verification in android

Tags: android, verification, sinch, one-time-password, sms-verification

I am integrating Sinch SMS Verification API in my app and half part is already done. So far, I am able to send and generate OTP request/response for given mobile number and receiving on that mobile number. However, when I try to VERIFY that received OTP wrong Callback gets fired.

Below is my code,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener, VerificationListener {

    private EditText editTextVerify;
    private Button buttonVerify;

    private Config config;
    private Verification verification;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextVerify = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextVerify);
        buttonVerify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonVerify);
        buttonVerify.setOnClickListener(this);

        config = SinchVerification.config().applicationKey("5xxxxx9c-xxc-4***-a***-76xxxxxb1xx1").context(getApplicationContext()).build();
        verification = SinchVerification.createSmsVerification(config, "91xx**xx**", this);
        verification.initiate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("...button clicked...");
        verification.verify(editTextVerify.getText().toString().trim());
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitiated() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("...calls onInitiated...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitiationFailed(Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e instanceof InvalidInputException) {
            // Incorrect number provided
            System.out.println("....onInitiationFailed exception... " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } else if (e instanceof ServiceErrorException) {
            // Sinch service error
            System.out.println("....onInitiationFailed exception... " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } else {
            // Other system error, such as UnknownHostException in case of network error
            System.out.println("....onInitiationFailed exception... " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerified() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("...callls onVerified this....");
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e instanceof InvalidInputException) {
            // Incorrect number or code provided
            System.out.println("....onVerificationFailed exception... " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } else if (e instanceof CodeInterceptionException) {
            // Intercepting the verification code automatically failed, input the code manually with verify()
            System.out.println("....onVerificationFailed exception... " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } else if (e instanceof IncorrectCodeException) {
            // The verification code provided was incorrect
            System.out.println("....onVerificationFailed exception... " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } else if (e instanceof ServiceErrorException) {
            // Sinch service error
            System.out.println("....onVerificationFailed exception... " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } else {
            // Other system error, such as UnknownHostException in case of network error
            System.out.println("....onVerificationFailed exception... " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Whenever I enter received OTP or wrong OTP in the Text Box & click Submit button below callback gets fired this Callback

```
@Override
public void onInitiationFailed(Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e instanceof InvalidInputException) {
        // Incorrect number provided
        System.out.println("....onInitiationFailed exception... " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } else if (e instanceof ServiceErrorException) {
        // Sinch service error
        System.out.println("....onInitiationFailed exception... " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } else {
        // Other system error, such as UnknownHostException in case of network error
        System.out.println("....onInitiationFailed exception... " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Ideally, it should fire below Callback

```
@Override
public void onVerificationFailed(Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e instanceof InvalidInputException) {
        // Incorrect number or code provided
        System.out.println("....onVerificationFailed exception... " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } else if (e instanceof CodeInterceptionException) {
        // Intercepting the verification code automatically failed, input the code manually with verify()
        System.out.println("....onVerificationFailed exception... " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } else if (e instanceof IncorrectCodeException) {
        // The verification code provided was incorrect
        System.out.println("....onVerificationFailed exception... " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } else if (e instanceof ServiceErrorException) {
        // Sinch service error
        System.out.println("....onVerificationFailed exception... " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } else {
        // Other system error, such as UnknownHostException in case of network error
        System.out.println("....onVerificationFailed exception... " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Referred links :
https://www.sinch.com/docs/verification/android/#verificationlistener

Answer (score 1):

I would try placing the *onVerified* callback right after the *onInitiationFailed* method. This should then allow the OTP response to pass through the *onVerificationFailed* callback.

Here's the documentation for the Verification Listener:
http://download.sinch.com/docs/verification/android/latest/reference/index.html

Comment: Tried as you suggested but not worked. Please check the question, edited your suggested way. Not working